# Sequence to draw a HighStock chart with multiple getJSON calls

Tags: javascript, getjson, highcharts

I'm building a webpage that displays a HighStock chart with several sets of series retrieved with a separate `$.getJSON` call for each set.  I'd like to display some part of the chart while the user waits for the sets to load, and add the series as they come in.  What is the best way to sequence drawing the chart and making the `$.getJSON` calls?

My efforts so far have been error prone, with HighStock returning issues, gaps in graphs, graphs that stop displaying their data, etc.  I think that my poor understanding of the asyncronous nature of the `$.getJSON` call is part of the problem also.

Answer (score 0):

You can always for first series create chart, and for each next series use `chart.addSeries()`  to add series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Ha8Lt/

Comment: Thankyou.  That was very helpful.  How do I force the series to appear in the same order every time despite different load times for each getJSON call?

Comment: You can set legendIndex for each series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/JaFkm/ also zIndex you can set for series. But you can't force to appear in the specific time order - only by displaying chart after all series are loaded.